# What is the difference between TreeList and Droptree in sitecore?

Tags: sitecore

I am working on sitecore projects but I have limited knowledge of sitecore controls.
Can anyone show me the difference between TreeList control and Droptree control, in which scenario I have to use each of them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Treelist stores multiple items and the droplist only one.

Both stores the IDs of items under the hood.

Treelist: `{BB14F070-0ACE-4AD8-A18B-DD053C0F9419}|{6F8FA16D-ED29-4F05-BA2A-21251D7EE2B5}`
Droplist: `{BB14F070-0ACE-4AD8-A18B-DD053C0F9419}`

Also there are differences when accessing those type using Sitecore's API. You need a cast to the appropriate type, then you can play around with its properties...

```
var referenceField = (ReferenceField)Sitecore.Context.Item.Fields["DroptreeFieldName"];         
var multilistField = (MultilistField)Sitecore.Context.Item.Fields["MultilistFieldName"];
```

About the usage, when you need a reference only to one item goes with the droptree, if you need reference to multiple items use the treelist. By the way, I've just had to create two components, one to show a silgle profile and other to list a few profiles. The first I used a droptree and in the second a Treelist.

hope that helps..
cheers